# C# Need Help Changing a Label.Text - My Function/method won't change my Form Label Text

Tags: c#, text, label

I wanted to make a function to organize my code better but this is giving me a headache, My Problem is that I want to use my Public Function to change the label.Text whenever I call them from the Form but it's not working. How can I get this working and please be very basic. Thank You.

Here's my Code:

```
namespace NoSleepHD
{
    public partial class NoSleepHD : Form
    {
        public NoSleepHD()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void selectFolder(string driveLabel, string writePath)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog Tree = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            Tree.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
            Tree.ShowNewFolderButton = false;
            Tree.Description = "Please Select any Drive OR Folder on Your External hard Drive";
            Tree.ShowDialog();
            if (Tree.SelectedPath.Length != 0)
            {
                driveLabel = Tree.SelectedPath.ToString();
                Properties.Settings.Default.WritePath01 = driveLabel.ToString();
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            selectFolder(Label11.Text, Properties.Settings.Default.WritePath01);
        }
```

but Label11.Text does not show any Text. Can someone  kind please help me out. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it wouldn't: you're passing a string `Label11.Text` to the function.  Pass the `Label11` object only and set its text in the selectFolder function.

Comment: Sorry but how do i exactly set its text in the selectFolder function? When I select driveLabel.something something. it only has 4 options which of none is text.

Comment: Since these two functions are in the same class, why don't you just call    Label11.Text = Tree.SelectedPath.ToString(); inside the selectFolder function.  This way, you don't even have to pass the first parameter (string driveLabel)

Comment: I would do that if I only had 1 Label but I have 10. Also if i did that, I probably wouldn't need the Function to organize the code, Plus I bumped into something I could probably use in the future if I actually learned how to do it correctly. Hopefully with your help? ^^

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  If you have 10 labels that are linked to folder locations, it would be better to do it this way (notice that the Click handler is using sender, so you can use this handler for all the label buttons, no need for separate handlers).

```
public void selectFolder(Label label, string writePath)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog Tree = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        Tree.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
        Tree.ShowNewFolderButton = false;
        Tree.Description = "Please Select any Drive OR Folder on Your External hard Drive";
        Tree.ShowDialog();
        if (Tree.SelectedPath.Length != 0)
        {
            label.Text = Tree.SelectedPath.ToString();
            Properties.Settings.Default.WritePath01 = label.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }

    private void FolderSelector_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        selectFolder(sender as Label, Properties.Settings.Default.WritePath01);
    }
```